# Link to foreign key in JQGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, jqgrid-asp.net

I have designed my jqgrid viewmodel as follows,

```
public class DomainJQGrid
{
    public JQGrid DomainsGrid { get; set; }

    public DomainJQGrid()
    {
        DomainsGrid = new JQGrid
        {
            Columns = new List<JQGridColumn>()
            {
                new JQGridColumn
                { 
                    DataField = "DomainId",
                    PrimaryKey = true,
                    Editable = false,
                    HeaderText = "Domain ID",
                    Visible = false                        
                },
                new JQGridColumn
                {
                    DataField = "ClientId",
                    Editable = false,
                    Width = 150,
                    HeaderText = "Client"
                },
                new JQGridColumn
                {
                    DataField = "DomainName",
                    Editable = false,
                    Width = 150,
                    HeaderText = "Domain Name"
                },
                new JQGridColumn
                {
                    DataField = "Registered",
                    Editable = true,
                    Width = 100,
                    DataFormatString = "{0:d}",
                    HeaderText = "Registered",
                }

            },
            AutoWidth = true,
        };
        DomainsGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowRefreshButton = true;
    }
}
```

And I am binding the datasource to using my controller as follows.

```
return gridModel.DomainsGrid.DataBind(hmEntity.DomainProducts);
```

in the above model, instead of my **ClientId**, how can I bring **ClientName** from my Client table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you'd like to be able to define a column that uses a property of an object property.

Assuming you have a property of type Client, named Client, you'd want to be able to do something like:

```
DataField = "Client.ClientName"
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. There may be a different notation that can be used for this, but I couldn't find any documentation when I ran into this scenario.

For the sake of getting past the issue, and at the cost of dirtying up the model, I chose to add a property to support the grid. It's on my 'technical debt' list and am hoping to find a better solution when I pay that back.

If you want to suffer that same burden :), add this to your DomainProduct class (again, assuming you have a Client property):

```
[NotMapped]
public string ClientName
{
    get { return Client == null ? "" : Client.ClientName; }
}
```

And then just use ClientName for the DataField value.

Comment: Thanks @Mufaka, It helped me using [NotMapped] annotation.